# Как в модели SQLALchemy создать свойство класса, а не экземпляра?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица `Source` которая связывается с моделью `Task` через таблицу `sources_tasks` по "методу" Many-To-Many. Также в этой модели определил 2 свойства, которые возвращают динамическое значение, где из БД возвращается всего 2 записи (как мне и нужно):

```
sources_tasks = db.Table('sources_tasks',
    db.Column('source_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sources.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('task_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
)

class Source(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'sources'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    dt_from = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow, index=True)
    dt_to = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(2048), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    update_period = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1440)
    is_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=True)

    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('sources', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='select') # One-To-One

    # В relationship левая сторона это Source, а правая сторона это таблица Task, т.е. Source связывается с Task:
    tasks = db.relationship('Task',
                            secondary=sources_tasks, # Промежуточная таблица
                            primaryjoin=(sources_tasks.c.source_id == id),
                            secondaryjoin=(sources_tasks.c.task_id == Task.id),
                            backref=db.backref('sources', lazy='dynamic'),
                            # order_by=db.desc(Task.id),
                            lazy='dynamic') # Many-To-Many

    @property
    def last_tasks(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_last_tasks'):
            self._last_tasks = self.tasks.filter( ((Task.start_dt != None) & (Task.finish_dt != None)) | (Task.finish_dt == None) ) \
                                        .order_by(db.desc(Task.id)).limit(2).all()
        return self._last_tasks

    @property
    def current_task(self):
        if len(self.last_tasks) > 0 and self.last_tasks[0].finish_dt is None:
            return self.last_tasks[0]
        return None
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что, если у меня несколько `Sources` в БД, то для каждой записи в БД которая отражается в модели будет вызваться отдельный SQL запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks, sources_tasks 
WHERE sources_tasks.source_id = ?
  AND sources_tasks.task_id = tasks.id 
  AND (tasks.start_dt IS NOT NULL AND tasks.finish_dt IS NOT NULL OR tasks.finish_dt IS NULL)
ORDER BY tasks.id DESC
```

Если записей 50, то будет 50 SQL запросов. Это плохо. В идеале, я бы хотел получить 2 записи на каждый экземпляр `Source`, но при этом был бы всего 1 SQL запрос, как например это делает `relationship` в SQLAlchemy. Например, вот эта связь c `lazy='subquery'` генерирует один SQL запрос для всех моих `Sources`:

```
last_tasks = db.relationship('Task',
                            secondary=sources_tasks, # Промежуточная таблица
                            primaryjoin=(sources_tasks.c.source_id == id),
                            secondaryjoin=((sources_tasks.c.task_id == Task.id) & (Task.start_dt != None) & (Task.finish_dt != None)),
                            order_by=db.desc(Task.id), # Get last task
                            uselist=True, viewonly=True, lazy='subquery') # One-To-One
```

Получается следующий SQL запрос:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT sources.id AS sources_id 
          FROM sources 
         WHERE ? = sources.user_id 
           AND sources.dt_to IS NULL) AS anon_1 
  JOIN sources_tasks AS sources_tasks_1 
    ON sources_tasks_1.source_id = anon_1.sources_id 
  JOIN tasks 
    ON sources_tasks_1.task_id = tasks.id 
   AND tasks.start_dt IS NOT NULL 
   AND tasks.finish_dt IS NOT NULL 

ORDER BY anon_1.sources_id, tasks.id DESC
```

Всё бы хорошо, но возвращает `relationship` избыточное количество записей, которых может быть 500 или более, а мне нужны только 2 первые записи из этого `relationship`. Если бы в `relationship` был бы параметр что-то типа limit=2, которая ограничивала бы выборку из БД, то моя проблема была бы решена.

Как сделать так, чтобы небыло запросов к БД для каждого из экземпляров?

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем, кто хоть сколько потратил время на мой вопрос, но ответ уже нашёл. Не вдаваясь в подробности, ответ - использовать [column-property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)

В моём случае проблема решается так:

```
sources_tasks = db.Table('sources_tasks',
    db.Column('source_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sources.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('task_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
)

class Source(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'sources'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    dt_from = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow, index=True)
    dt_to = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(2048), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    update_period = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1440)
    is_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=True)

    # Загружается как колонка-подзапрос в родительском SELECT
    next_update_dt = db.column_property(
        db.select(columns=[db.func.coalesce(Task.deferred_dt, datetime.utcnow())])
        .where((sources_tasks.c.source_id == id) & (sources_tasks.c.task_id == Task.id) & (Task.finish_dt == None))
    )

    # Загружается как колонка-подзапрос в родительском SELECT
    last_update_dt = db.column_property(
        db.select(columns=[Task.finish_dt])
        .where((sources_tasks.c.source_id == id) & (sources_tasks.c.task_id == Task.id) & (Task.finish_dt != None))
        .order_by(Task.finish_dt.desc())
        .limit(1)
    )
```